# Dynamically change the size of cells and spacing in grid layout android

Tags: android, grid-layout

I have a textview inside a grid layout and I want to change the size of grid cells according to the text area of the text view. If the word size is 5, then the grid size will be calculated accordingly. I am adding both the textview and the grid dynamically. I used the below code for this text area calculation,

```
        text[i].setText(String.valueOf(finallist.get(i)));
        text[i].measure(0, 0);
        int widths = text[i].getMeasuredWidth();
        params.width=widths;
        text[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        text[i].setTextSize(10);
```

where 'params' is the layout params for the textview. When I run this code, I am getting output as shown below.

[image: output]

Here I am getting extra spaces in between the grids no matter the textview size is wrapped. Instead I wanted the grid layout to occupy the area if it's available. I wanted the output like this,

[image: expected]

I wanted equal spacing between the grids. How can I achieve this DYNAMICALLY .Also I am implementing drag and drop here. I am new to this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to use grid layout and calculate size of text etc...stuff !! Just use chip text view , google on it ,it will gives you output as you want . you can refer https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView this.

Comment: I am placing the textview inside the gridlayout. Will the grid adjust its size when i use chip text view ? @Radhey

Comment: I am implementing drag and drop in grid layout too. @Radhey

Comment: make one demo project first , remove your gird view and set chip text for sample PLUS perform drag and drop operation on textview ,as you can get click events of text also , as per mine opinion no need to use grid view as you want only textual data .

Comment: Any possibility we could do using rowspan or column span or row spec @Radhey

Comment: Amm ! using row span ,you can't get the exact wrap content of your text view .To check this , you can make one xml file and ad sample data and cross check this .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127760/discussion-between-radhey-and-anusha).

Comment: use flowlayout instead of grid layout

Answer (score 0):

Use [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) instead of normal [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). A good example of Staggered Grid layout manager will be found [here](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9yiv8m0bBhw/VnQSZ01KfiI/AAAAAAAAcLE/_54K6cOmegE/s1600/AndroidRecyclerViewStaggeredGridLayoutManager3.png).

> A LayoutManager that lays out children in a staggered grid formation. It supports horizontal & vertical layout as well as an ability to layout children in reverse. Staggered grids are likely to have gaps at the edges of the layout. To avoid these gaps, StaggeredGridLayoutManager can offset spans independently or move items between spans. You can control this behavior via **setGapStrategy(int).**

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Any chance I  could do it using rowspec , colspec or span? I am implementing drag and drop in grid layout @aa_oo

Comment: @Anusha, I am not sure. I have never worked with drag n drop grid layout. sorry. But I am pretty sure you can, since it's android! :p

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GridLayout.Spec` as it has both `rowSpec` and `columnSpec` properties.Also try `setAlignmentMode` asit used for all of the alignments between the children of its container.

Comment: Can you give me an example for this @Shahrair Nazim Real

Comment: why not!! [How to use GridLayout.Spec for a column extending multiple rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924875/how-to-use-gridlayout-spec-for-a-column-extending-multiple-rows) and [Set ColumnSpan and ColumnWeight programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234271/set-columnspan-and-columnweight-programmatically)
Also [Android: Create grid with dynamic size in gridlayout or gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314550/android-create-grid-with-dynamic-size-in-gridlayout-or-gridview) is what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). Take a look at the readme at the GitHub project site. I think you will find that it will fit your needs. There is also a FlexboxLayoutManager for RecyclerView. This is all supported by Google.